# Errors while moving react project into client folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So the time has come to build the backend of the application. But I'm having a lot of errors after I moved the project into a client folder as suggested in a few youtube videos. And I have also created a server folder which is empty for now. How can I solve this?
I really have no idea on where to start, or what to do sadly.

this is a list of errors:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 20:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js 217:12-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 19:15-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 12:17-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\destroy'


ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\dotenv\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 3:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 5:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 18:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\etag'


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 28:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 42:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 22:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 23:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 29:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 31:18-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 16:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\express\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 1:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\mime'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\mime'


ERROR in ./node_modules/parseurl/index.js 13:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\parseurl'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/safer-buffer/safer.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\safer-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\send'


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 39:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 43:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 45:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 20:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 24:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\Serma\Desktop\Tribeto\Tribeto\client\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your node modules and package lock JSON file
Do editing in the path whatever you want, run npm install and sleep relaxed

Btw where are you deploying backend because I also want to deploy the backend

Comment: I cant answer that question, im very new to this and just following some tutorials

Comment: Deploy on Heroku for beginners

Comment: So i just did what you said, deleted and installed again. But I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: tried for second time and it works thanks.